# React devtools not recognising dev mode in laravel

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-devtools

I'm trying to get devtools working properly for Reactjs profile on my laravel projects. The tools say that my projects aren't in dev mode. My react version is sufficient (v18.2 vs required 16.5 for react profile). Since Vue devtools recognise dev mode but react devtools don't (for both FF and Chrome), I assume it's something at the react level.

My .env has `APP_ENV=local` and I'm using `npm run build --watch`. Here's my package.json for a react project.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "watch": "vite build --watch",
        "clean": "vite clean"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.2",
        "@inertiajs/react": "^1.0.0",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",
        "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.5",
        "postcss": "^8.4.18",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "source-map": "^0.7.4",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
        "d3": "^7.8.4",
        "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
        "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
        "react-select": "^5.7.3",
        "unop-react-dropdown": "^0.2.3"
    }
}
```

My vite.config.js is

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig(({command, mode}) => {
    console.log('Vite mode:', mode);

    return {
        plugins: [
            laravel({
                input: 'resources/js/app.jsx',
                refresh: true,
            }),
            react(),
        ],
        define: {
            'process.env.APP_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode),
        },
    };
});
```

I added the `process.env.APP_ENV` definition on advice found elsewhere, but it didn't help.

Any other ideas where to look?

Answer (score 0):

As per Vite's documentation for the [build command](https://vitejs.dev/guide/cli.html#build)...

> Build for **production**.

If you want to run the `build` command in a [mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#modes) other than `production`, pass the `-m` / `--mode` option

```sh
npm run build -- --mode development --watch
```

Comment: That looked like it should work, but I'm still getting the error. I definitely have a high enough version, but with this I'm equally sure that it's in dev mode now, so I really have no idea why it's not working.

Comment: @maganthro I just remembered that with `npm` you need to use `--` before any extra options you want to pass to the underlying script

Comment: Thanks for trying. Still no change. I just see this. `Profiling support requires either a development or profiling build of React v16.5+.`